# Javascript "Cannot set property" of 3d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I trying to set value in 3d javascript array...

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = [];
var array = [a,b,c];
array[0][0][0] = 'value';
```

This code return error: "Cannot set property '0' of undefined" but 2d array working normally:

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
var array = [a,b];
array[0][0] = 'value';
```

Comment: Neither of those is a 3d array.  They are both 2d arrays.

Comment: Don't you see that `[a,b,c]` is simply an array with three elements? Imagine it would be `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a 3D array, thats a 2D array, literally translated to:

```
[[],[],[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

in your first example you do not have a 3-dimensional array.
what you have is `[[],[],[]]` - an array with 3 parallel arrays in it.
this is why you can not access `array[0][0][0]` since the deepest you get is 2 levels. this is why your code in the second example works.

I think you got confused with the arrays at all. maybe you should read about programming, arrays and the whole idea again?

---

If you want to have an array with 3 leves, this is a nice example: an array in an array which is in an array itself

```
var a3l_a = [[[]]];
// equals:
var a3l_b = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```